# tomcat logs to be stored in a separate file

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I have developed an spring mvc application which is executing perfectly on tomcat , but the logs I am getting of the server tomcat is on console , I want that logs to be stored in a file ,in other words I want tomcat logs and events that are shown on console to be get stored on a file , I have tried log 4j of apache and below is the properties file I am using ...

```
    ### direct messages to file or.log ###
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/logs/springmvc.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1} - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.append=true

### set log levels - for more verbose logging change 'info' to 'debug' ##
log4j.rootCategory=ALL, file
log4j.logger.Demo=\=debug
log4j.logger.org.eclipse=debug
```

and the main class.. on which I want log.info statements to be get recorded..

```
public class HelloWorldController extends AbstractController{
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Returning hello view");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");
        model.addObject("msg", "saral saxreva");

        return model;
    }
}
```

but still the logs are not generated in separate file , please advise as I am stuck up on this.

Comment: Did you initialized Logger to use that file appender?

Comment: @JigarJoshi Please advise what I need to do for that , It will be a great help if you could post here with changes

Answer (score 0):

Does the springmvc.log file even created when your program starts? That's a first indication of whether or not the log4j is being picked up properly.

- Make Sure the log4j properties file is in the correct location and are picked up properly
- Double check the import statement for your logger and LogFactory classes (just to make sure they are using the log4j ones

If the log4j is set up properly, you'll see springmvc.log file created when the app starts.

Then in the log4j properties, try:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,file
```

and also get rid of the other 2 that you have

```
log4j.logger.Demo=\=debug
log4j.logger.org.eclipse=debug
```

Comment: did you see the springmvc.log file gets created?

Comment: @tsOverflow..no Man , and that the cause of worry , Please advise , could you post the modifications here

Comment: Have you verified you put the log4j properties file in the correct place? and you import the correct Log / LogFactory classes from a log4j library? ... follow: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/

Answer (score 0):

I think for enabling logging in web app you need some listener (or servlet) that will initialize it. For example in Spring you need to define in your web.xml such listener:

```
<!-- This listener is necessary to enable log4j logging -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

In internet there are a lot of info about this. Here is the firs [link](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-initialize-log4j-in-a-web-application.html) from google. Here is another one [link](http://blog.idleworx.com/2010/01/setting-up-log4j-for-simple-java-web.html) where describet how to init logger in servlet or in listener without Spring.

And also it is better to use *log4j.rootLogger* instead of *log4j.rootCategory* because last is deprecated.